# Android Wheel imageView

Tags: android

I want to create application, which its user can choose randomly number from wheel imageview, I used [this](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu) but, I want that wheel must still rotate by given velocity - according to the power user drags - and this velocity must decrease into zero.

Second, in this example, the rotation is working  on touch only, how make the wheel rotate after that.